# [web development]How to highlight a portion of my site(like a button or a paragraph) when a new user signs up?

Tags: web, highlight

How to highlight a portion of my site like a button or a inputbox when a new user signs up(for giving the user some info).if you don't get what i mean.[Go to this site](http://cloudsigma.com).

Answer (score 0):

There may be easier ways to do this depending on what framework you use, but the basic idea would be to have the registration page pass a variable to the first landing page the user sees.  If that variable is set, then apply a certain style to the div or span or input or button or whatever element you want.  How exactly you do that depends on the framework you're using.  The site you linked to uses (among other things), jQuery.  Using jQuery you could do something like this:

URL directed to after registration:
http://example.com/landing.html?firstlogin=true

Javascript:

```js
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}  

var firstTimeLogin = getUrlParameter('firstlogin');
if (firstTimeLogin === 'true')
{
    $("div#specialContent").addClass("highlight");
}
```

CSS:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

There are a lot of other ways to do this (you could use cookies instead of URL paramaters, or read the URL parameter more efficiently if you're using some other web development framework), and some of this might not work (if your #specialContent has a background color set that the .highlight class can't override, for example).  But this is the general gist of how you could achieve that effect.

Comment: Thank you very much dnfield.It will have costed me 1 day

Comment: No problem.  If this answer was helpful and you think it answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer for future users!